# Android: download file from internet using DownloadManager and save it to the internal memory

Tags: android, memory, storage, internal, download-manager

I am downloading a file from the web to my Android device using `DownloadManager`. I am saving this file on the sdcard using:

```
DownloadManager.Request req = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse("file path"));
req.setTitle("file title").setDescription("Downloading ....") // download the package at the /sdcard/download path.
.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "file name"+ "file extension");
```

I want to save it to the internal storage. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

use this path `.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
             +"/Android/data/xxx.xxx.xxx/files/")`

Comment: I am getting permission denied! what type of permissions do i need?

Comment: This is for saving in external storage.