# Android: Save data to internal memory using Download

Tags: android, storage, internal, download-manager

I am downloading file from a server in Android using the `DownloadManager` class. I want to store this file in the internal memory of the device. I tried to use `.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/Android/data/xxx.xxx.xxx/files/")` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340853/android-download-file-from-internet-using-downloadmanager-and-save-it-to-the-in), but it is not working. How to solve my problem?

Comment: "but it is not working" - What problems are you facing?

Comment: You will get permission error if you do this

Comment: @ user370305: I am getting:  No such file or directory

Comment: Use getFilesDir(); like, .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir( getFilesDir());

Answer (score 0):

add

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to manifest.xml and create "/Android/data/xxx.xxx.xxx/files/" path

Comment: I am using this permission, but still getting: No such file or directory

Comment: Try only this path .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())

Comment: I want my files to be saved in the internal memory of the device and not in the sdcard.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
File testDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/Android/data/xxx.xxx.xxx/files/");
```

and

```
if (!testDirectory.exists()) {
    testDirectory.mkdirs();
        }
```

Comment: Not working, the setDestinationInExternalPublicDir method is not applicable for (File, String)

Comment: run above code before execution of `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir `